# difference between ng generate application <app-name> and ng new <app-new>

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

I know the difference that `ng generate application <app-name>` works only in angular  app folder. but what are the other differences.

Comment: The flags verbose and collection are not available with ng generate application

Comment: `ng new` creates a new workspace that contains a single application. `ng generate application` adds a *new* application to the *existing* workspace.

Comment: @KirkLarkin : any docs where i can find it in details ?

Comment: The closest thing I could find is the message output by `ng new --help`: *Creates a new directory and a new Angular app.* and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-projects) on multiple projects.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ng new NAME` create a new workspace with a default application

`ng g application NAME` create a new application in an existing workspace

The official documentation does not explain this in full details. So I'll recommend dig out some blogs posts that make introductory post for it. Such as the following:

[Angular 6 Workspace](https://medium.com/@angularlicious/angular-6-workspace-test-drive-cfe24bbceeb3)

Answer (score 7):

**ng init:** create a new application in the current directory

**ng new:** create a new directory and run ng init inside the new directory.

**ng generate:** add features to your existing application such as adding modules, 
                 components and services etc. The generate command and the different sub- 
                 commands also have shortcut notations, so the **ng g** commands are 
                 similar to the **ng generate**

Answer (score 5):

## TL;DR:

- `ng new <app-name>` creates a new workspace **and** (by default) a new application in that workspace.
- `ng generate application <app-name>` creates a new application within an **existing** workspace.

## Detailed Info

Multiple sources are referenced in case you want to read up on things a bit more. But here's a good overview.

### Overview

**Workspace** - A collection of Angular projects (that is, applications and libraries) powered by the Angular CLI that are typically co-located in a single source-control repository (such as git).
Source: https://angular.io/guide/glossary#workspace

> You develop applications in the context of an Angular workspace. A workspace contains the files for one or more projects. A project is the set of files that comprise a standalone application or a shareable library.
>
> The Angular CLI ng new command creates a workspace.
>
> `ng new <my-project>`
>
> When you run this command, the CLI installs the necessary Angular npm packages and other dependencies in a new workspace, with a root-level application named `my-project`. The workspace root folder contains various support and configuration files, and a README file with generated descriptive text that you can customize.
>
> By default, ng new creates an initial skeleton application at the root level of the workspace, along with its end-to-end tests. The skeleton is for a simple Welcome application that is ready to run and easy to modify. The root-level application has the same name as the workspace, and the source files reside in the `src/` subfolder of the workspace.

Source: https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#workspace-and-project-file-structure

> When you generate an additional app or library in a workspace, it goes into a `projects/` subfolder.
>
> A newly generated app contains the source files for a root module, with a root component and template. Each app has a `src` folder that contains the logic, data, and assets.

Source: https://angular.io/cli#workspaces-and-project-files

### Examples

#### Workspace Without an Application

Creating a new project using the `--createApplication=false` flag so no application is created within the workspace (the default is `true`). Notice there is not a `projects` or `src` folder in our workspace.

`> ng new my-workspace --createApplication=false`

[image: Create a new workspace without an application using ng new]

Now go into the workspace folder that was created and generate an app and you will see that there is now a `projects/my-app` folder in our workspace.

`> cd my-workspace`
`> ng generate app my-app`

[image: Create an application in the workspace using ng generate]

You can also create a second app in the workspace using `ng generate` again and you will see both applications in our workspace.

`>ng generate app my-other-app`

[image: Create another application in the workspace using ng generate]

#### Workspace With Application

The alternative and more common approach for smaller projects is to create the workspace and app at the same using `ng new` **without** the `createApplication` flag (or by setting it to `true`). Here you will get a workspace with the `src` folder that contains our app.

`>ng new my-app`
OR
`>ng new my-app --createApplication=true`

[image: Workspace and application created with ng new]